# Add full-stop after every 4th character in Javascript, but not at the end of the string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some js that will allow me to remove any colons and dashes in a string, then add a full stop after every 4th character, but not at the end of the string.

So for example `xx:xx-xx-xx-xx:xx` would become `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`

I'm not the greatest with js but I've been able to write some code that gets rid of the colons and dashes, but I'm now a bit stuck with adding the full stops. THis is what I have so far:

```
<form>
Input: <input type="text" id="mac" name="macAddress">

<button onclick="convert(); return false;">Convert</button>

    <div id="outputDiv"></div>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

function convert() {

        var mac = document.getElementById('mac').value;
        var mac2 = mac.replace(/\:|-/g,"");

        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML= mac2;

};


</script>
```

I've had a look around at similar topics, I recon I might be able to put something together that would add the full stops but I'm not sure how I would stop it from adding one at the end of the string. Would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
mac2 = mac2.replace(/(.{4})(?!$)/g , '$1.');
```

(.{4})
.(dot) is any character, and {4} means exact 4 times of any characters

(?!$)
is assertion to match not followed by $, where $ is ending

/......../g
use g to make it global replace

'$1.'
$1 is backreference of content in the first ( )

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead to avoid putting the dot at the end of the string:

```
"xx:xx-xx-xx-xx:xx".replace(/[:-]/g,"").replace(/(.{4})(?!$)/g, "$1.")
// xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
function convert(mac) {
    mac = mac.replace(/\:|-/g,"");
    mac = mac.replace(/(....)(?!$)/g, "$1.");
    console.log(mac);

    return mac;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` on a string to split it to an array, and then `join` on the array:

```
str = "12345678abcdefgj"
arr = str.match(/.{1,4}/g)
// arr == ["1234", "5678", "abcd", "efgj"]
arr.join('.')
// "1234.5678.abcd.efgj"
```